# Wordpress plugin path configuration

Tags: wordpress, git, plugins

I am working on a local environment and I am pulling down a plugin that has its own git repository that is linked to the production server (also staging server). The only problem is that the plugin folder itself is in a folder like so:

```
repository-folder
   real-plugin-folder
```

And my plugins directory looks like so:

```
plugins
    plugin1
    plugin2
    plugin3
    repository-folder
        real-plugin-folder
    plugin4
```

Is there a way to define a new path for this one particular plugin so that it will show up in my local environment and so I can edit it while keeping the plugin git repository structure in contact so I can push up to that repository? (some sort of path definition in wp-config.php?).

I think Git submodules might be the answer? But honestly I don't have time to tinker with it: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just start your repo in "repository-folder" ? You don't need to follow the same parent folder in git.

I hope it helps you at least a clarification [here](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)

Comment: Because the repository is already set up the way it is for the production servers and staging servers, idk who set it the way they did but I don't want to mess with it and would rather just make modifications on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux environment, setup a symlink for the plugin:

```
cd plugins
mkdir real-plugin-folder
ln -s respository-folder/real-plugin-folder/plugin.php real-plugin-folder/plugin.php
```